# Scandit barcode scanner is not working with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Scandit barcode scanner for my phonegap app. 
This is simple code example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">
        function onBodyLoad()
        {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

    function success(resultArray) {

    //console.log("Scanned " + resultArray[0] + " code: " + resultArray[1]);
        var scan = resultArray[0];


        console.log(scan);

        }

        function failure(error) {
            alert("Failed: " + error);
        }

        function scan() {

            cordova.exec(success, failure, "ScanditSDK", "scan",
                         ["Here is my app key..............",
                          {"beep": true,
                          "1DScanning" : true,
                          "2DScanning" : true}]);
        }


        </script>

    <div align="center" valign="center">
        <input type="button" value="scan" onclick="scan()" style="margin-top: 230px; width: 100px; height: 30px; font-size: 1em"/>
    </div>

</body>
```

But after importing my jquery.js and jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js libraries its not working anymore.  Is there some solution for it?  Any clue why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same issue in using JQM 1.3. But I was able to fix this problem with the integration only of the button in the page. Then I added the Scandit code into an external JS file that I referred to in the header part of my index file.